# DHCP providing IP but not creating DNS A record

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server, ubuntu-22.04, windows-dns

I'm having a problem setting up a virtual machine IP assignment via DHCP.

The virtual machine is a clean installation of Ubuntu Server 22.04 The DHCP server is a Windows Server Domain Controller.

When the Ubuntu Server boots, it obtains an IP address and I can see that IP in the Lease of the DHCP management application within Windows. However, in the same Windows machine, the DNS A record is not created.

I have the following options in the DNS tab of the DHCP scope properties window:
Enable DNS dynamic updates according to the settings below: Always dynamically update DNS records

Discard A and PTR records when lease is deleted

Dynamically update DNS records for DHCP clients that do not request updates (for example, clients running Windows NT 4.0)

What can be missing on the configuration that is causing the DNS A record to not be created?

I've already double checked the configuration of the DHCP and DNS services; I've checked that other machines obtain the DHCP and register themselves on the DNS.

Best regards

Comment: you really run a DC on a dhcp setup? do I correctly understood that every reboot the AD server mentioned, is getting a different IP?!

Comment: `Dynamically update DNS records for DHCP clients that do not request updates` That setting should not be necessary given that the other setting to always update is enabled. Should at least remove that.

Comment: @djdomi do please learn to read. The DHCP server is the DC, and so has a static IP.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know only windows operating systems support dynamic update in dns by default. You need to configure the nsupdate tool on your Ubuntu server.

Answer (score -1):

Since your client is not Windows, it gets denied writing to the zone by default. You can control this via the dynamic updates setting shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Check Ubuntu Server Configuration:in file **/etc/network/interfaces** should smth like **iface eth0 inet dhcp**

Check DHCP Server Configuration:
Ensure that the DHCP server on your Windows Server Domain Controller is configured to allow dynamic DNS updates. You've mentioned the settings, but double-check that "Enable DNS dynamic updates according to the settings below" is selected, and it's set to "Always dynamically update DNS records."

Verify DNS Client Settings on Ubuntu Server:
Check that the DNS client settings on the Ubuntu Server are configured to register with the DNS server. You can do this by editing the **/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf** file and making sure it contains the following line:

**send host-name = gethostname();**
This line tells the DHCP client to send its hostname to the DHCP server for DNS registration.

of course Check DNS related Logs at server and client